# Higher order function sort() used it with other higher order function its working with let content also

Tags: ios, swift

So, any reason behind happen this things, because when i perform sort() function with let type at that time xcode give me a compile time error

i tried it in my playgound with only sort function and sort() function with other higher order function.

like so

```
let name = ["mehul","HeLLi","JeniFER","Ankul"]
name.sort()
```

error :

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'name' is a 'let' constant

but with other higher order functions

```
let nameStartingWithBArray = name.filter {$0.first != "B"}.map {$0.uppercased()}.sorted()
```

now there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [sort func](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort) you are using is the **mutating func**, that means sort function internally sort the array in the same variable.

**Mutating Func :** To modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) *its properties from within the method*, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends.

So. `let` doesn't allow `sort` for doing mutating, so you need to make it var.

More ever, if you use [sorted(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) , it returns new array of sorted values. So here you don't get any error.

Answer (score 4):

Please consider the subtle but crucial difference between *sort* and *sorted*

- `sort` has no return value. It sorts in place that means the calling object is mutated.
- `sorted` ( as well as `filter` and `map`) returns a new object with the result of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

[**sort()**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort) basically works with the list itself. It modifies the original list in place. The return value is None.
`name.sort()` sorts the list and save the sorted list.

**[sorted()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641066-sorted)** works on any iterable that may include list, dict and so on. It returns another list and doesn't modify the original list.
sorted() returns a sorted copy of the list (a new sorted list), without changing the original list.

**Keynote** : **sort()** is faster than **sorted()**

Answer (score 1):

The [`sort`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort) function *sorts the collection in place* - i.e. it modifies the array, `name`, on which you call `sort`.

[`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) on the other hand returns an array and does not modify the original array.

Compare `sort` with [`sorted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641066-sorted) which again returns a new array and does not modify the original array.

So, you can write

```
let sortedNames = name.sorted()
```

`sortedNames` will be in order, while `name` will be in the original, unsorted, order.

If you write

```
var name = ["mehul","HeLLi","JeniFER","Ankul"]
name.sort()
```

then `name` will be in order, and because it is declared as `var` rather than a constant with `let` the change is permitted.